# Can I have a 240V and 120V on the same circuit?

Tags: electrical, circuit

I know absolutely nothing about electricity. I would like to have a sauna and whirlpool bath in my home. The sauna draws 6kW, so it uses 6000/240 = 25 amps. The whirlpool bath says it requires a dedicated 15 amp circuit with GFCI outlet. This is on the second floor far away from the electrical box, and as part of the build, the builder put for me a 6/3 wire in the attic right above the space for future projects. As you all know, this is rated for 55 amps, which is plenty for both projects. I have a few ideas, if you can call them that:

1. Use the 6/3 wire for both the sauna and whirlpool bath. In this situation, would I be able to have both running at the same time?
2. Use another existing circuit for the whirlpool tub. The home is probably 14 wire, so there would be 15 amps here. The upstairs rooms have LED lights, so there's really not much more draw from the rooms. However, would I be able to make it GFCI in this case? And does the tub really need 15 amps... I can't imagine that.
3. Run another separate wire there for a dedicated circuit just for the tub.

3 obviously is the cleanest solution, but it would involve significantly more work. Can you comment on options 1 and 2 or give any other recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest probably use the 6/3 to a sub panel and then run the two circuits from that.  A 40 or 50 feeder breaker for the sub

Comment: You must obey the instructions.  They say must have it's own circuit then that is what is required.  Does not matter if it only uses one amp and you have a circuit close by that only uses one amp also, and can save a circuit and a breaker.

Comment: The great thing about the subpanel suggestion from crip659 is that a subpanel magically converts the single 6/3 feed you have now into the two separate circuits that are required for the sauna and whirlpool bath.

Comment: Thank you both. That is exactly what I will do!